# how to convert columns having x,y,z coordinates of csv file into one column representing RGB?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

i am working on CMU Motion Capture data set.It represents human skeleton by 31 joints and records x,y,z location of each joint. Hence these become 31*3=93 joints.  I have converted x,y,z coordinates positions of human joints into form of columns in a csv. Lets suppose x column represents R channel, y column represents G channel and z column represents B channel. Can someone please guide me how can i merge three columns into one column, so it may become an RGB(0,1,2)?  My csv looks like this.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/dz3ul5oi1yha6th/stack.csv/file

i have included link for sample csv. thanks

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to add your CSV.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: That's a *"picture"* of your CSV and very hard to read into a Python variable. Please paste the actual text of the CSV. What sort of answer are you expecting - an image? a Numpy array?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes i am looking to convert into an RGB image.

Comment: Would you be able to put 31 lines of CSV directly into your question please? I don't really want to wade through pages of consent about what rubbish MediaFire wants to store on my computer. Thank you. Also, could you explain what sort of shape image you are expecting from these 31 RGB pixels because it seems like a prime number so you can only be expecting a 31x1 or 1x31 image?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments it would be better to post examples of input and desired output at least.
Assuming that you only need to combine columns as lists into new columns then you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
# load csv into a dataframe
df=pd.read_csv('your.csv')

# combine columns as lists into newcolumns
df['root_xyz']=df.iloc[:,0:3].values.tolist()
df['lhipjoint_xyz']=df.iloc[:,3:6].values.tolist()
df['femur_xyz']=df.iloc[:,6:9].values.tolist()
# ... keep doing the same thing for every group
# last group
df['whatever_xyz']=df.iloc[:,90:93].values.tolist()

# save to csv if required
df.to_csv('yournew.csv')
```